# How to transform SVG circle animation into text?

Tags: html, svg

```
<svg width="1000" height="100">
 <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />

<animate 
       xlink:href="#orange-circle"
       attributeName="cx"
       from="50"
       to="900" 
       dur="2s"
       begin="0s"
       values="50; 990; 760; 900"
       keyTimes="0; 0.7; 0.8; 1"
       fill="freeze" 
       id="circ-anim"/>
</svg>
```

I tried writing this instead of the line with the circle:

```
<text id="textAnimation" x="25" y="25" font-size:24">Learn Now!</text>
```

but the text doesn't have the animation (yes, I've changed the id #orange-circle to #textAnimation)

Comment: text does not have a cx attribute.

Comment: okay, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the cx to x, fixing the href and correcting the style syntax error on the text element makes it animate for me.

```html
<svg width="1000" height="100">
 <text id="textAnimation" x="25" y="25" style="font-size:24px">Learn Now!</text>

<animate 
       xlink:href="#textAnimation"
       attributeName="x"
       from="50"
       to="900" 
       dur="2s"
       begin="0s"
       values="50; 990; 760; 900"
       keyTimes="0; 0.7; 0.8; 1"
       fill="freeze" 
       id="circ-anim"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: ah, so the attributeName does really have a specific purpose. Thank you very much.

Comment: any idea why the text won't change its color if I add a color attribute for style?

Comment: ask another question, be sure to include what you're doing so we can see the problem.